# Nginx -- Can't use mDNS domain name in upstream server

Tags: nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mdns

## Minimal example

Machine A and B, where B uses mDNS with domain name `b.local` and set ssh service at port 2222. A and B does not turn on firewall.

In machine A's `nginx.conf`:

```
stream {
    upstream b-ssh {
        server  b.local:2222;
    }
    server {
        listen      2222;
        listen      [::]:2222;
        proxy_pass  b-ssh;
    }
}
```

When using `nginx -t` to test this configuration on machine A, error occurred:

```
[emerg] host not found in upstream "b.local:2222"
```

However, in machine A, using `ssh -p 2222 b.local` works normally (`-4` or `-6` is also tested)

## Possibly useful infos

In my real-world example, machine A is a Windows 11 which disables all firewalls; machine B is WSL2 ubuntu 21.10 inside machine A which uses avahi-daemon mDNS service.

In side machine A's `nginx.conf`, I also set an HTTP proxy pass:

```
http {
    server {
        listen  8929;
        listen  [::]:8929;
        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://b.local:8929;
        }
    }
}
```

**and this works well even though this uses mDNS domain name**.

If I replace mDNS domain name with its real IP in upstream server, the SSH proxy works.

Answer (score 0):

Install `libnss-mdns` and make sure there's an entry for mdns in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:          files mdns [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

You can test mdns resolution with `getent`:

```bash
getent hosts b
```